# VSCode Terminal cannot find ‘make’ 'g++', but the standard Windows Console can

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw32

I can run 'make' or 'g++' in standard Windows Console, but I can't run them in VSCode Terminal.

I try to use VSCode Terminal to run ‘make’ or 'g++', but it cannot find these commands:

```
C:\CEngineering\VSCpp> make --version
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\CEngineering\VSCpp> g++ --version
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However, the **standard Windows Console runs well**:

```
C:\Users\cb> make --version
mingw-get version 0.6.3-pre-20170905-1
Copyright (C) 2009-2013, MinGW.org Project

This is free software; see the product documentation, or source code,
for copying and redistribution conditions.  There is NO WARRANTY; not
even an implied WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, nor of FITNESS FOR ANY
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\cb> g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
Copyright (c) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I don't know why I cannot run in VSCode Terminal. I have checked the VSCode terminal setting and they are the **same** program (*C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe*), but different results... strange

Comment: If something is properly in your PATH, both should find it just fine.

Comment: Have you restarted VSCode since you installed mingw and updated `PATH`?

Comment: Yes I restart but it still doesn't work. Maybe the problem is that the VSCode is launching its terminal with some different setting.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I find some solutions...

Please try:

Solution 1: re-install VS Code to a path **without** blank. I put it to `C:\VSCode`

Solution 2: Set your VS Code Properties

- √   Run this program as an administractor

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Open VSCode from the standard Windows Console (simply by calling `code`), when you do that environment variables will be passed to VSCode.